# Counting negative eigenvalues of a Hessian.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f:M\to\Bbb{R}$ be a Morse function. The number of negative eigenvalues of the Hessian at a non-degenerate critical point is the index of $f$ at that critical point.

When counting negative eigenvalues, do we count the number of distinct eigenvalues or multiplicity? For instance, if the Hessian is $\begin{pmatrix} -2&0\\0&-2\end{pmatrix}$, does it have one negative eigenvalue, or two?

Comment: Since the idea is to count the number of dimensions in which the function is concave, I'd say you count multiplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You *do* count multiplicity.**

The reason is fairly simple: there is no "prefered" coordinate system on $M$.

Suppose we are working in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Fix a chart $x:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by the identity map.

Consider the function $f:(a,b)\to a^2+b^2$. At $(0,0)$, a critical point of $f$, the Hessian is $$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$ if we use $x$ as our chart.

Fix another chart, $y:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2,~(a,b)\mapsto(\frac{a}{2},b)$. In this new coordinate system, $f$ is given by $f\circ y^{-1}:(a,b)\mapsto(2a,b)\mapsto 4a^2+b^2$. The Hessian of $f$ at $(0,0)$, using $y$ as the chart, is given by $$\begin{bmatrix}8 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}.$$

The number of positive and negative eigenvalues is the same, but we cannot say much more than that because we have different charts.

Comment: +1: Good answer. I'd say it even more explicitly: The value of an eigenvalue of a quadratic form $q$ *depends on the norm* $n$ of the vector space in question. It's something of a minor miracle that the index of the critical point is constant under smooth (orientation-preserving?) coordinate changes without reference to a Riemannian metric. The Poincare-Hopf theorem is definitely a major miracle.